# Advanced Autosuggest Box (CSS styling + Category Grouping)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

I wonder if you can recommend a paid script which will create an advanced autosuggest box at my website? I need it to allow rich CSS styling. It should also group results by categories.

The best two examples of such autosuggest box are [BLOOMBERG TERMINAL](http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/10680/images/Bloomberg.jpg) and [REUTER EIKON](https://blogs.thomsonreuters.com/financial-risk/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2016/09/eikon-data-visualization-screenshot2.png).

**Click on the links** to see the images, which show the search bars of both.

If there is a software which can generate such autocomplete forms – kindly please let me know!)

Comment: I don't know any generic solution for this as a lot of small setup and fine tunning is needed for every case/website/service.

Autosuggestion feature ussually gets built from a JSON after to an API. THis is the easy part if every piece is in place. After that parsing the JSON is neither as difficult as it may seem if the information structure is good.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I wonder if there is a software which can generate such box from the list of entries? I have looked into such packages as https://www.syncfusion.com/ - not sure if they can be used for this purpose...

Comment: David - can you comment on this script - do you think it allows enough room for customization to achieve similar results?https://codecanyon.net/item/smart-suggest-advanced-autocomplete/80946

Comment: I really think you should aim for a total customized solution built from scratch. I see it was released in 2010 and it's a jQuery plugin, only that may bring you already some problems with your current infrastructure.

Creating an autossuggestion is not as difficult as it may seem. I would encourage you to really try to do it yourself as I think no general comercial solution may work for you 100% out of the box. 

Just my opinion anyway.